# Linux ubuntu can load grub after deleting windows 8.1 dual boot see reults.txt below

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

```
Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1   976,773,167   976,773,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda8           2,048   887,986,175   887,984,128 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda9     887,986,176   896,135,167     8,148,992 Swap partition (Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda8        e4653f63-c6de-4ee1-9bd1-98a22257aa00   ext4       
/dev/sda9        e4c019b0-a232-4f9b-80e0-fe1a5fb6f8b2   swap       
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS amd64

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)


=========================== sda8/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
```

Answer (score 1):

You removed EFI partition. That's why Ubuntu does not boot.

This can be fixed by creating a 500 MB fat32 partition and installing grub using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).